# HashSet behavior when changing field value

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, hashset

I just did the following code:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class MyClass {

    private static class MyObject {
        private int field;

        public int getField() {
            return field;
        }

        public void setField(int aField) {
            field = aField;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            boolean result = false;
            if (other != null && other instanceof MyObject) {
                MyObject that = (MyObject) other;
                result = (this.getField() == that.getField());
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return field;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<MyObject> mySet = new HashSet<MyObject>();
        MyObject object = new MyObject();
        object.setField(3);
        mySet.add(object);
        object.setField(5);
        System.out.println(mySet.contains(object));
        MyObject firstElement = mySet.iterator().next();
        System.out.println("The set object: " + firstElement + " the object itself: " + object);
    }

}
```

It prints:

```
false
The set object: MyClass$MyObject@5 the object itself: MyClass$MyObject@5
```

Basically meaning that the `object` is not considered to be in the set, whiile its instance itself apparantly is in the set. this means that if I insert a object in a set, then change the value of a field that participates in the calculation of the `hashCode` method, then the `HashSet` method will seize working as expected. Isn;t this too big source of possible errors? How can someone defend against such cases?

Comment: Use immutable objects. There are more reasons for using them. However, if you have mutable objects they should not be used as hash keys.

Comment: Use mutable or effective immutable objects as key. nice question +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the quote from Set API. It explains everything.

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 3):

`HashSet` is implemented on `HashMap`.

`HashMap` caches the `hashCode` of the `key`, So if you change the `hashCode` than even though the hash function maps the `hashCode` to the same bucket as the original object present but it will not find because before even checking the object equality it will check the `hashCode`.

see the line:

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
```

And if the `hashCode` maps to different bucket by hash function than the original object is present than obviously it can't find.

So even though same object if you change the hashCode hashSet can't find. Hope it helps.

**So key for the HashMap or the object that you are putting into HashSet should be immutable or effective immutable.**

@fazomisiek

```
public HashSet() {
       map = new HashMap<E,Object>();
   }
```

Similarly if you check the source of HashSet you can find it.

Comment: "HashSet is implemented on HashMap." oO

Answer (score 0):

This problem is just a limitation of the implementation of `java.util.HashSet` and the underlying `java.util.HashMap`. Fundamentally, you're trading off the ability to modify elements in the set for faster insert/lookup performance - it's just part of the contract of using a hash set / map data structure.

If you can't guarantee everybody will remember they can't modify the objects in the set, the only way to absolutely guard against this happening is to only insert immutable objects into the set in the first place.